# GNUPLOT illegal day of month at midnight

Tags: gnuplot

gnuplot throws illegal day of month, when my data file rolls over at midnight.

Im using Gnuplot 4.6.6
(i've seen the same issue with 5.0)

Gnuplot:

```
reset
set decimalsign locale
set datafile separator "\t"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S" #21.01.2015 07:16:17;
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
plot 'exam.txt' using 2:3 with lines
```

My Data:

```
16.06.2015  23:59:51    11,92048    -9,94011
16.06.2015  23:59:55    11,92318    -9,60236
16.06.2015  23:59:58    11,92403    -9,49577
17.06.2015  00:00:02    11,92261    -9,67415
17.06.2015  00:00:06    11,92398    -9,50203
17.06.2015  00:00:09    11,92233    -9,70848
```

Has anyone a suggestion whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two things: To parse a four-digit year value you must use `%Y`, and the time is in the first column. So, provided, that the data and the time are separated by a normal space only, and the other columns are separated by a tab (this information gets lost on stackoverflow), then the following should work fine:

```
reset
set decimalsign locale
set datafile separator "\t"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
plot 'exam.txt' using 1:2 with lines
```

In general, I would recommend you either to use a clearly recognizeable column separator (like `;`), or just leave the default to treat any white space as column separator.

Parsing of a time format which is spread over multiple columns (the first two in your case) works fine. In the using statement you must then give the column number where the time data starts. To access any other column but the time column, the counting goes as usual, i.e. to plot all data you would need to use

```
reset
set decimalsign locale
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
set style data lines
plot 'exam.txt' using 1:3, '' using 1:4
```

Comment: The TAB between time and date seems to be the main problem!
many thanks!